# Is there a way to verify a value given in request is present in response or not in postman?

Tags: javascript, postman-testcase

I have given a parameter in request(eg:date=2020-03-12) I need to verify the same date is present in response or not, by not giving the value(2020-03-12) directly in script. Because this date is dynamic and will be changed often. So I need to check the value of the date given in request is present in response using the date variable alone. I hope the question is clear

Comment: Show your trials and errors

Answer (score 0):

Both the Request and Response objects are available when testing, so you can check that a value is present.  Assuming json payloads:

```
pm.test('Response contains data from Request', function () {
    const RequestJSON = pm.request.json();
    const ResponseJSON = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(RequestJSON.Text).to.equal('Request Text in Text field');
    pm.expect(ResponseJSON.Text).to.equal('Request Text in Text field');

    // Or if you do not care about the field data
    pm.expect(RequestJSON.Text).to.equal(ResponseJSON.Text);
});
```